# How to (and should I) avoid repetition while assigning values from different sources?

Tags: python

In a Mako template partial I accept an argument (`step`) that can be an instance of `Step` class, a `dict` or `None`. Can I in some way avoid repetition or do the check in other more 'pythonic' way? Or how could I gracefully avoid checking types at all?

```
<%include file="_step.mako" args="step=step" />
```

and then in `_step.mako`:

```
<%page args="step"/>
<%! from package.models.recipe import Step %>
<% 
if isinstance(step, Step):
    number = step.number
    time_value = step.time_value
    text = step.text
elif type(step) is dict:
    number = step['number']
    time_value = step['time_value']
    text = step['text']
else:
    number = 1
    time_value = ''
    text = ''
%>
```

Comment: actually, the most pythonic way would be to avoid passing different types to this partial.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I wolud gladly avoid that, but how can I maintain a single template that is rendering a form sometimes empty and sometimes repopulated (with dict or instance of a class).

Comment: you shouldn't. You should change the rest of your code so its consistently passes the same thing to this template.

Comment: @WinstonEwert like create a dummy (empty) dict for none, valid or invalid data and pass that dict to the template? You know, I started with such a design but faced a problem: if I repopulate invalid data - it can only be a dict (I do not allow creating instances from invalid data) and if its valid - it is an instance and I have access to its attributes. So if I want to access its attributes in the template I have to check (or `try`) if its an instance. But if I unify the the type of object passed to the template,  and it can only be a dict, I guess, no attributes  like methods, can be used.

Comment: Why do you need to populate this form with invalid data? Shouldn't you just not tolerate invalid data?

Comment: Ok, I have a `step` entity that requires a _number_ and _text_ and an optional _time value_. A user enters number and time value but leaves the text field empty. When I redirect after failed `step` creation I want to repopulate number and time value fields and mark the empty text field with error message.

Comment: ah, I see. What web framework are you using?

Comment: Pyramid, but it's kind of fundamental question for me - I faced the same problem while on Zend Framework. Maybe it's because I don't utilize tools like Deform (and Zend_Form) that do the render-validate-repopulate job, but that's my style.

Comment: You may find it useful to look into some of those projects, just to see how they solve this problem. Basically, they would have a `StepForm` class which can hold invalid/blank/valid data. The class would have methods to convert to/from an actual Step object. In some ways, its not dissimilar to always using a dictionary. But you get some benefits of using an object as well. You don't have to go for the whole form generation technique these libraries go for, but the separation between model and form objects has been widely adopted and seems to work well.

Comment: Right! I am definetely close to stepping through Deform code for the final answers. Thanks for your attention Winston!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.I assume `if type(step) is dict:` should be `elif type(step) is dict:`.

2.`isinstance` is preferable than `type` because `isinstance` caters for inheritance, while checking for equality of type does not (it demands identity of types and rejects instances of subtypes).

3.You also can apply duck-typing.

```
try:
    number = step.number
except AttributeError:
    try:
        number = step['number']
    except KeyError:
        number = 1
```

And these ways are quite pythonic.

4.I suggest you can inherit your `Step` class from `dict` then you don't need to check types. Yo will just do

```
number = step.get('number', 1)
time_value = step.get('time_value', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I will apply duck-typing as you described for now and save inheriting `dict` for later experiments - that could finally be a perfect solution.

Comment: You are welcome. But consider that `number = step.get('number', 1)` is shorter version of `try: number = step['number'] except KeyError: number = 1`

Comment: I will. The Step class is used as a model and an sqlalchemy mapping, thats why I'm afraid messing with it.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use inheritance however.  Just provide an implementation of the `get()` method and let the ducks do their thing.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function (thanks to San4ez):

```
def failsafe_get(object, name):
    if object:
        try:
            extractor = attrgetter(atrr_path)
            result = extractor(object)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                result = object[atrr_path]
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                result = None
    else:
        result = None
    return result
```

Now I can use it in a template like this:

```
<div class="number">${failsafe_get(ingredient, 'unit.abbr')}</div>
```

No repetition, but maybe performance issue.

UPD. I've implemented `operator.attrgetter` so now I can give dotted notation for a name.

Comment: I would check `name is None` out of `try-except` block

Comment: @San4ez I am actually checking if `object` is `None`, providing `name` always a `str`. Corrected the code.